# Fixing ODBC SQL Server Driver Error on Linux

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, centos, odbc

### The Problem

I am trying desperately hard to setup an ODBC connection to an MSSQL database via PHP. However, when I try to connect via PHP, I get the error:

> SQLDriverConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib
> '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-11.0.so.2270.0' : file
> not found

### What I have tried...

I have played around with several things:

1. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/cc46c7e8-0034-428f-87b7-508543b810b4/sql-server-native-client-for-linux-odbc
2. `ldd /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-11.0.so.2270.0`
3. `strace -f isql -v 'ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server' 'Username' 'Password'` (I think this syntax is actually wrong)

My Linux experience simply isn't good enough to resolve this myself, can anyone suggest what I can do, or what the issue is?

Comment: See with : http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/hh568454%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: @toto21 That has nothing to do with the issue, that explains how to install it, those are the instructions I followed in the first place!

Comment: Hope this URL helps you: http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/php/sql_server_unix_tutorial.html

Comment: What is the output of your 2. (ldd)?